# Automatic add openapi file in helidon project

Tags: java, openapi, helidon

I want instrument for automatic generate openapi in my helidon project (Java 1.8, helidon SE 1.3.1)

I read documenttation/example and make:

1. add depends in maven
2. add openapi.yml in META-INF
3. add endpoint for router.
4. add apifilter and apimodelreader

pom.xml:

```java
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.helidon.openapi</groupId>
   <artifactId>helidon-openapi</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

main.java:

```java
return Routing.builder()
                .register(JsonSupport.create())
                .register(health)                   // Health at "/health"
                .register(metrics)                  // Metrics at "/metrics"
                .register("/file", fileService)
                .register("/card", cardService)
                .register(OpenAPISupport.create(config))
                .build();
```

application.yaml

```
openapi:
  filter: ru.ittest.feezio.openapi.SimpleAPIFilter
  model:
    reader: ru.ittest.feezio.openapi.SimpleAPIModelReader
```

Now I have openapi document in endpoint: http://127.0.0.1:8456/openapi
And it is my openapi.yml. But I don't want write by hand openapi.yml, I want auto generate yml for my classes: fileService and cardService. This classes work and response success (API work, I make documentation now)

Comment: I understand - it is inposibel and wrote yml himself, by hands. How hosting it in my server? (now I hosting in swagger.io as trial)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the OP noted, Helidon SE cannot automatically generate the OpenAPI document for your app. You provide *either* a static `openapi.yml` file *or* your own model reader and/or filter classes. You can provide the static file and the classes if you want to but that is not required. For other interested readers here's the [doc](https://helidon.io/docs/latest/#/openapi/01_openapi).

Probably most developers who want OpenAPI support in their Helidon SE app will use a tool to define their API and then export the OpenAPI document from the tool, adding that YAML file to their application JAR (typically at `META-INF/openapi.yml`).

Note that if you use Helidon MP (which implements MicroProfile OpenAPI) and add the normal JAX-RS annotations to your endpoints, then Helidon MP can generate the OpenAPI document for you automatically. Here's [the doc](https://helidon.io/docs/latest/#/microprofile/08_openapi) for that.

Comment: Thanks, I write openapi.yml by hand, no auto.